# Searching in list of lists & functions

Tags: python, list, function, search

So i need to search if an item is in the first column of a list of lists and if it is, print the item. I have to do this using functions.

```
CD = input("Enter name of CD database: ")    

def createDatabase(CD):      #opens and creates list
    aList = []
    file = open(CD) 
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip().split(",")    #strip \n and split at ,
        aList.append(line)      #add lines into formerly empty aList
    for i in range(len(aList)):
        aList[i][3] = float(aList[i][3])    #override line for price to be float
    return aList

aList = createDatabase(CD)

def PrintList(aList):
    for line in aList:
        album = str(line[0])   
        artist = str(line[1])
        genre = str(line[2])
        price = str(line[3])
        print("Album: " + album + " Artist: " + artist + " Genre: " + genre + " Price: $" + price)
    return


def FindByTitle(aList):
    target = input("Enter Title to Search: ")
    for item in aList:
        if target in aList:
            print(target)
        else:
            print ("Title not found")
    return aList

PrintList(FindByTitle(aList))
```

The output i'm getting from this is

```
Enter name of CD database: CD.txt
Enter Title to Search: Sempiternal
Title not found
Title not found
Title not found
Title not found
Album: Sempiternal Artist: Bring Me The Horizon Genre: Metalcore Price: $14.5
Album: Badlands Artist: Halsey Genre: Indie Pop Price: $19.95
Album: Wildlife Artist: La Dispute Genre: Post Hardcore Price: $9.6
Album: Move Along Artist: The All American Rejects Genre: Punk Rock Price: $10.2
```

and am not entirely sure how to do or fix my search function. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Add some sample data and input (replace the `input` expressions with strings) to your question so we can run the code.

Comment: `if target in aList:` is not correct. `if target in item:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can early return in your `FindByTitle` function once you have found a match. If the control flow reaches out of the loop you can be sure that the criteria was not met and return failure.

```
def FindByTitle(aList):
    target = input("Enter Title to Search: ")
    for item in aList:
        if target in item:
            print(target)
            return aList # return here
    print("Title not found")
    return None
```

In case you need to return all possible lists, keep a count which can be used to find whether there was at least one match

Comment: that worked perfectly, however, is there a way i can get it to search only the first set of elements, because so far it's printing the correct output but then 'title not found' three times for each of the other lines of the list

Comment: actually got that sorted.
One final question though, is there a way i can get it to print only the target? Because it is still printing the target as well as the entire list again after it.

Comment: Simply omit the print statement you have in the end.

Answer (score 0):

In function FindByTitle change `alist` to `item` in line 4
because you are searching target in alist which is nested list instead search in  lists generated by loop

```
def FindByTitle(aList):
target = input("Enter Title to Search: ")
for item in aList:
    # change here
    if target in item:
        print(target)
    else:
        print ("Title not found")
return aList
```